# Azure - Log Analytics query with powershell variable

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-automation, azure-log-analytics, kql

I have prepared simple powershell script for creating Log Analytics computer group. Based on that group I want to add VMs to the Update Management solution in Azure. Command presented below. For now I can add few VMs using this structure `'Heartbeat | where (Computer == "vmA" or Computer  == "vmB")'`. This approach is good for few VMs, question is what can I do with a list of 50 or more VMs? Is there any way to pass variable/param to this `-Query`?

```
 New-AzOperationalInsightsComputerGroup `
-ResourceGroupName "testRG" `
-WorkspaceName "Testloganalytics" `
-SavedSearchId "testID01" `
-DisplayName "GroupName" `
-Category "Updates" `
-Query 'Heartbeat | where (Computer == "vmA" or Computer  == "vmB")' `
-Version 1 `
-Force
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a variable which contains all the vms like this:

```
$myvms = '("vm1","vm2","vm3","vm4","vm5")'
```

then, for the `-Query`, you can use the [in operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/inoperator), the command like below:

```
-Query "Heartbeat | where Computer in $myvms"
```

Comment: The problem is when I am using suggested solution, in my Log Analytics I have query like --> `Heartbeat
| where Computer in vmA vmB vmC
| distinct Computer`. And this formt is not accepted by Log Analytics query language. I need --> `Heartbeat
| where Computer in ("vmA","vmB","vmC")
| distinct Computer`

Comment: @tester81, did you define the $myvms like mine? there're two single quote at the beginning and at the end.

Comment: Hi, and one last question, what about adding VMs dynamically, for example if I want to create a list of VMs based on the txt file content? is it possible to use it in my approach?

Comment: @tester81, yes, it's possible. The guide looks like this: you should write powershell script to read all the vm names from the .txt file, then concatenate them in the format like `$myvms`. Please let me know if you have any concerns:).